# TFS 2008 - Check In Policy to ensure that a solution item is not remove

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to create a check in policy that will not allow you to remove a particular solution item from the solution? I want to make sure that the testrunconfig file is not removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx how to create a custom check-in policy